# Does gcc convert uint8_t to int for single values?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, implicit-conversion, type-conversion

If I compile the following program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t N = 10;
    uint8_t int8Value = 42;

    std::vector<int> IntVector(N, 0);
    for (int & ele:IntVector) {
        ele += int8Value;
    }

    std::vector<uint8_t> Int8Vector(N, 0);
    for (uint8_t & ele:Int8Vector) {
        ele += int8Value;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%i %i\n",IntVector[i],Int8Vector[i]);
    }
}
```

with `g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -Wconversion` on `gcc 4.9` it spits out the folowing warning:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:16:7: warning: conversion to ‘uint8_t {aka unsigned char}’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
ele += int8Value;
   ^
```

So if I understand it correctly this means that the compiler converts the single value of `uint_8` to `int`? Is this because of memory alignment?

On the other hand if I try something like:

```
uint8_t int8Value = 342;
```

it throws me an `overflow` warning and trancates the result. Also

```
printf("%i\n",sizeof(int8Value));
```

returns the expected `1`.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, arithmetic expression causes conversion to `int`. See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Numeric_promotions).

Comment: Ah okey thank you. So the `+` is the problem then. The line `uint8_t A = 42,B = 23,C = A + B;` also spits the warning which confirmes this. Should I be worried about this in terms of performance?

Comment: @magu_ No you should not need to worry, it should all be handled at compile time.

Comment: @magu_: typically there are no separate "8-bit" arithmetic operations on machine level anyway - the compiler is going to emit code doing the arithmetics on "native" words and masking as necessary to get the lowest eight bits.